# Inner join query return more than one row?

Tags: mysql

I dont no what is the problem with the below query. It returns 12 rows instead of single row. Kindly suggest me whether below query is correct or not. If not, correct the problem in below query. Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT 
    M.name, MR. review, MAN.running_time, MC.screen_name, MI.producer, 
    MI.director,MI.story, MI.bgm_score,MI.screenplay, MI.music,
    MS.story, MS.screenplay, MS.dialogue, MS.direction, MS.music, MS.bgm, 
    MS.cinematography, MS.characterization, MS.shotlocation, MS.editing, 
    MS.production, MS.performance, CC.certificate FROM tttbl_review_language RL 
JOIN tttbl_censor_certificate CC 
JOIN tttbl_movie M
INNER JOIN tttbl_movie_review MR ON MR.movie_id=M.id
INNER JOIN tttbl_movie_analytics MAN ON MAN.movie_id=M.id
INNER JOIN tttbl_movie_cast MC ON MC.movie_id=M.id 
INNER JOIN tttbl_movie_info MI ON MI.censor_id=CC.id AND MI.movie_id=M.id
INNER JOIN tttbl_movie_score MS ON MS.movie_id=M.id 

WHERE M.id=1
```

Comment: i would suggest its the `JOIN` you have at the top of your joins, rather than `INNER JOIN`

Comment: @ Takarii, still it returns 12 row after changing JOIN to INNER JOIN.

Comment: Join and Inner join are the same

Comment: Please provide more info! What are the primary keys of your tables? How many languages do you have in tttbl_review_language (since you don't filter the table in the WHERE section of your query)? On which column do you want to join tttbl_censor_certificate and tttbl_movie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not  `on condition`  between `tttbl_review_language RL,  tttbl_censor_certificate CC and  tttbl_movie M` 
then these table could produce a cartesian product with other result ..

```
    select 
    M.name, 
    MR. review, 
    MAN.running_time, 
    MC.screen_name, 
    MI.producer, 
    MI.director,
    MI.story, 
    MI.bgm_score,
    MI.screenplay, 
    MI.music,
    MS.story, 
    MS.screenplay, 
    MS.dialogue, 
    MS.direction, 
    MS.music, 
    MS.bgm, 
    MS.cinematography, 
    MS.characterization, 
    MS.shotlocation, 
    MS.editing, 
    MS.production, 
    MS.performance, 
    CC.certificate 
    FROM tttbl_review_language RL 
    JOIN tttbl_censor_certificate CC 
    JOIN tttbl_movie M  
    INNER JOIN tttbl_movie_review MR ON MR.movie_id=M.id  
    INNER JOIN tttbl_movie_analytics MAN  ON MAN.movie_id=M.id 
    INNER JOIN tttbl_movie_cast MC ON MC.movie_id=M.id 
    INNER JOIN tttbl_movie_info MI ON MI.censor_id=CC.id AND MI.movie_id=M.i
```